# Multi upload files with input

Tags: vue.js

How to multi upload files with tied input block?
And store this in an array of objects  [image]

Comment: The file input name could be `files[]` and the text `file_texts[]`. One array index in *files* will then match with an array index of *file_texts*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://www.concentrationcode.com/uploading-100-vue/) link may help you with the multiupload part, the only thing that you need to change is the `addFile` part. We just need to modify it a bit.

First of all, modify the state to be `const state = reactive({files, fileName: ''})` and then the `addFiles` function to this:

```
const addFiles = (event) => {
  const file = event.target.files[0]
  const blob = file.slice(0, file.size, file.type);
  const newFile = new File([blob], state.fileName, {type: file.type});
  state.files.push(newFile)
}
```

If you want several inputs, then just modify the `addFiles` `state.fileName` to change it to an array and use `state.fileNames[index]` to use that name.